# Sum of string in cloned TXT file

Tags: java, list, io

My task is to create a couple of methods which will process txt file and return proper input.
TXT file have two lines:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 7 3 4 6
```

My output in processed new TXT file should look like this:

```
 1+2+3+4+5=15
 2+7+3+4+6=22
```

Method to solve this :

```
- simple file writter - done 
- readLinesFromFile and put it inside the List<String> - done 
- take the lines from List<String> and process them and copy propper output to new TXT file. - Not Done
```

My main class should look like this:

```
   public void process(String fileName, String resultFileName) throws IOException {
        List<String> linesFromFile = fileProcessor.readLinesFromFile(fileName);
        List<String> resultLines = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String line : linesFromFile) {
            resultLines.add(NumbersProcessor.processLine(line));
        }
        fileProcessor.writeLinesToFile(resultLines, resultFileName);
    }
```

I stuck in method to process the resultLine so the actual third Method. I need to take the List of String 
proces it and paste the output to new file. To be honest I don't know how should I start.

To simplify this. I have List with this :

[1 2 3 4 5, 2 7 3 4 6]
and I need to have this :

1+2+3+4+5=15, 2+7+3+4+6=22
So I need to calculate the inside strings in line and receive a SUM from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To simplify this. I have List with this :
>
> [1 2 3 4 5, 2 7 3 4 6] and I need to have this :
>
> 1+2+3+4+5=15, 2+7+3+4+6=22

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = List.of("1 2 3 4 5", "2 7 3 4 6");
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s : list) {
            String[] nums = s.split("\\s+");
            int sum = 0;
            for (String n : nums) {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(n);
            }
            result.add(String.join(",", nums) + "=" + sum);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1,2,3,4,5=15, 2,7,3,4,6=22]
```

Comment: this is the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you'll need to convert into numeric values to be able to get your output.

Try using .split(" ") on the input string. This separates the input line into an array of strings holding all values.

This array can then be looped to

a) be put together again with the plus signs

b) convert each value to integer to be able to summarize the line result

I don't have an IDE at hand for actual code, but I hope it helps to find a start.